# ARM Assembly Language IDE on windows

Tags: windows, assembly, ide, arm

Is there any ARM Assembly Language IDE on windows (Like Eclipse,...) that I can write my instructions and have it simulate those?
How about on other platforms?
And how can I use them in detail?

Answer (score 2):

The Android SDK comes in a version for Windows, and that includes the Eclipse IDE; it includes a device simulator on which you can run the created code. If you add the Android NDK (Native Development Kit), you also get ARM crosscompilers. The Android simulator/emulator is actually a QEMU for ARM, it executes native ARM code.

In short: Get the Android [SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) / [NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) for Windows, and you'll have all of what you ask for - Eclipse IDE, ARM simulator, ARM crosscompiler/assembler.

Answer (score 1):

Both Visual Studio 2005 and 2008 allow you to write ARM assembly code and interactively debug it on an emulator or device. The only limits are that the emu/device must be Windows CE 4/5/6 and the compilers only support the ARMv4 and ARMv5 instruction sets.

If you can wait for the official release of Visual Studio 2011, it will allow full ARMv7A development to target WoA (Windows on ARM) devices.

Answer (score 0):

ARM and Keil provides IDE's that you can buy.
If you are talking about free ones, then I'm not aware of any.